# Mysql Stored Procedure Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Please need help:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getTodayCheckOuts`
BEGIN
    SELECT `tec_check_out`.`date`,`tec_check_out_items`.`check_out_id`,`tec_check_out_items`.`item_id`,CONCAT(`tec_items`.`name`,' - ',`tec_items`.`code`) AS 'name',SUM(`tec_check_out_items`.`quantity`) AS 'totla_qty',SUM(`tec_check_out_items`.`quantity`*`tec_check_out_items`.`price`) AS 'total_price'
    FROM `tec_check_out_items`, `tec_items`, `tec_check_out`
    WHERE `tec_check_out_items`.`item_id`=`tec_items`.`id`
    AND `tec_check_out_items`.`check_out_id`=`tec_check_out`.`id`
    AND DATE(`tec_check_out`.`date`) = DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY `tec_check_out_items`.`item_id`
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

keep getting this error

```
Error
Static analysis:
2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized data type. (near "." at position 163)
Unrecognized data type. (near "," at position 176)

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    SELECT `tec_check_out`.`date`,`tec_check_out_items`.`check_out_id`,`tec_' at line 2
```

Comment: can you mention where position 163 and 176 pointing to...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
/*
CREATE PROCEDURE `gettodaycheckouts`
*/
```

by:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `gettodaycheckouts`()
```

and

```
/*
GROUP BY `tec_check_out_items`.`item_id`
*/
```

by:

```
GROUP BY `tec_check_out_items`.`item_id`;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but now keep getting this error: `unexpected character (;) near GROUP BY tec_check_out_items.item_id;`